Bash: sum a number present in N lines before a given pattern
I have a kdenlive project file (which is basically a xml file) with a lot of text clips inside. I need to bulk edit the x coordinate of a certain text that appears multiple times. This is an example:
  &lt;position x="1316" y="553">
   &lt;transform>1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1&lt;/transform>
  &lt;/position>
  &lt;content line-spacing="0" shadow="0;#64000000;3;3;3" font-underline="0" box-height="94" font="Cambria" letter-spacing="0" font-pixel-size="80" font-italic="0" typewriter="0;2;1;0;0" alignment="4" font-weight="50" box-width="91" font-color="0,255,255,255">MIA!&lt;/content>
 &lt;/item>
 &lt;item type="QGraphicsTextItem" z-index="7">
  &lt;position x="1106" y="552">
   &lt;transform>1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1&lt;/transform>
  &lt;/position>
  &lt;content line-spacing="0" shadow="0;#64000000;3;3;3" font-underline="0" box-height="94" font="Cambria" letter-spacing="0" font-pixel-size="80" font-italic="0" typewriter="0;2;1;0;0" alignment="4" font-weight="50" box-width="91" font-color="255,255,255,255">6.5&lt;/content>
 &lt;/item>

I only need to edit the x coordinate concerning the text MIA!, which is 1316. What I want to do is add 40 to it and make the x coordinate become 1356.
In the file there are multiple MIA! texts with different x coordinates. What I need is a script that, given a number, for example 40, can sum it to the x coordinate and replace the value with the summed one every time there is a MIA! text.
My idea was a script that saves the x coordinate found 3 lines before the MIA! pattern in a variable, and then have a loop to sum 40 to every number. But I don't know how to replace the new values in the file.
#!/bin/bash
xcoord=`perl -ne 'push @lines,$_; print $lines[0] if /MIA!/; shift(@lines) if $.>3;' "$@"  | cut -d'"' -f2`
for word in $xcoord
do
final=$(( $word + 40 ))
....
done

The final output should be:
  &lt;position x="1356" y="553">
   &lt;transform>1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1&lt;/transform>
  &lt;/position>
  &lt;content line-spacing="0" shadow="0;#64000000;3;3;3" font-underline="0" box-height="94" font="Cambria" letter-spacing="0" font-pixel-size="80" font-italic="0" typewriter="0;2;1;0;0" alignment="4" font-weight="50" box-width="91" font-color="0,255,255,255">MIA!&lt;/content>
 &lt;/item>
 &lt;item type="QGraphicsTextItem" z-index="7">
  &lt;position x="1106" y="552">
   &lt;transform>1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1&lt;/transform>
  &lt;/position>
  &lt;content line-spacing="0" shadow="0;#64000000;3;3;3" font-underline="0" box-height="94" font="Cambria" letter-spacing="0" font-pixel-size="80" font-italic="0" typewriter="0;2;1;0;0" alignment="4" font-weight="50" box-width="91" font-color="255,255,255,255">6.5&lt;/content>
 &lt;/item>


Do you have actual, valid XML? Why do you have &lt; instead of < here? Can you give us an actual example of the XML and also the exact output you would want from it? If you're already using perl, why not do the whole thing in perl? Why make things complicated by trying to bring it back to the shell when perl is an exemplary tool for text processing?

&lt; is a standard tag that appears after every text in the project. The file is perfectly fine. I'll add the output I want to the OP. Also, the perl command that you see here is taken from another thread I found on here, as I'm not familiar with scripting language.

"I have a kdenlive project file (which is basically a xml file)" - what you're showing us is absolutely not an XML file. It's an encoded representation of something that may or may not be XML

This is what is reported in the first line of a project <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>. Anyway that is not important,  just treat as it was a text file.

Neverming, I've found a solution with sed and added it to the OP. Thanks for the interest.

"This is what is reported in the first line of a project <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" - then there should be < characters throughout instead of the entity &lt

I've moved your answer out of the question into its own answer. If you want to write your own (even if it's a straight copy) you'll get the points and the credit and we can delete the Community answer

Could be something like:
perl -0777 -pe '
  s{&lt;position x="\K\d+(?=.*?>([^>]*?)&lt;/content>)}{
    $& + ($1 eq "MIA!")*40
  }gse' your-file


Thank you. Elegant and working solution :)

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box without reading the whole input into memory and without reading the input twice:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v delta=40 -F'"' '
    /^ *&lt;position/ {
        xval = $2
    }
    xval == "" {
        print
        next
    }
    {
        buf = buf $0 ORS
        if ( /^ *&lt;content/ ) {
            if ( /MIA!/ ) {
                sub(xval,xval + delta,buf)
            }
            printf "%s", buf
            xval = buf = ""
        }
    }
' "$1"


$ ./tst.sh file
  &lt;position x="1356" y="553">
   &lt;transform>1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1&lt;/transform>
  &lt;/position>
  &lt;content line-spacing="0" shadow="0;#64000000;3;3;3" font-underline="0" box-height="94" font="Cambria" letter-spacing="0" font-pixel-size="80" font-italic="0" typewriter="0;2;1;0;0" alignment="4" font-weight="50" box-width="91" font-color="0,255,255,255">MIA!&lt;/content>
 &lt;/item>
 &lt;item type="QGraphicsTextItem" z-index="7">
  &lt;position x="1106" y="552">
   &lt;transform>1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1&lt;/transform>
  &lt;/position>
  &lt;content line-spacing="0" shadow="0;#64000000;3;3;3" font-underline="0" box-height="94" font="Cambria" letter-spacing="0" font-pixel-size="80" font-italic="0" typewriter="0;2;1;0;0" alignment="4" font-weight="50" box-width="91" font-color="255,255,255,255">6.5&lt;/content>
 &lt;/item>

To change the input file, if you use GNU awk then change awk to awk -i inplace or with any awk change ' "$1" to ' "$1" > tmp && mv tmp "$1".

Thank you! Tested and working fine :)

Answer moved from question

Found a solution by myself with sed:
sed -i "/$word/ {N; N; N; /MIA!/ s/$word/$final/g}" "$@"

First, sed searches for the coordinate by using the value found in the xcoord variable. Then, if after 3 lines the word MIA! appears, it will replace the value with the summed number found in the final variable.
#!/bin/bash
xcoord=`perl -ne 'push @lines,$_; print $lines[0] if /MIA!/; shift(@lines) if $.>3;' "$@"  | cut -d'"' -f2`
for word in $xcoord
do
final=$(( $word + 40 ))
sed -i "/$word/ {N; N; N; /MIA!/ s/$word/$final/g}" "$@"
done


You never need sed when you're using perl (or awk) and that would corrupt any other line that contained the value stored in word in any other context, e.g. if an MIA block had x="7" then when word is 7 in  the loop sed would change lines like &lt;position x="173" y="553" to &lt;position x="47" y="553" (note x="173" changed to x="47") and blocks like &lt;position x="1356" y="553"> .. shadow="0;#74000000;3;3;3" to &lt;position x="1356" y="553"> .. shadow="0;#474000000;3;3;3" (note #7... changed to #47... in shadow=...). It could also change the same x multiple times.

You are right! Thanks for letting me know, I wouldn't have noticed it otherwise
